# How to manipulate images and such in kivyMD

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I wrote this code but now i don't know how to manipulate my images so I am stuck i need help on how to
add images if i have multiple screens
and how to also add other labels so basically screen manipulation with multiple screens

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager


screen_helper = """
ScreenManager:
    MenuScreen:
    ProfileScreen:


<MenuScreen>:
    name: "menu"
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Profile'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'profile'

<ProfileScreen>:
    name: 'profile'
    MDLabel:
        text: 'Welcome Nate'
        halign: 'center'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Back'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.2}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'


"""


class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ProfileScreen(Screen):
    pass


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(ProfileScreen(name='profile'))


class DemoApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return screen


DemoApp().run()
```

Comment: you would have to add some code in classes `MenuScreen` and `ProfileScreen` instead of `pass` - but all this depends how you want to `"add images"`. If you want to add at start using some list of filenames, or you want to add them when you click on button, or you want to open window to select file from disk, etc.

Comment: Kivy doc: [Image](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.image.html), and [Basic Picture Viewer](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/examples/gen__demo__pictures__main__py.html)

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but the three lines in your code that involve `sm` are doing nothing and can be deleted.

Comment: @furas i want to add background images so how do i do that ?

Comment: @JohnAnderson okay thanks . It's always better to write neater and necessary code.

Comment: every widget has `Canvas` on which you can draw figures or put images. Some information from documentation: [Adding a Background to a Layout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/widgets.html?highlight=background#adding-a-background-to-a-layout)

Comment: you may also try put `Image` and other elements put inside `Image`. OR you may try to use [FloatLayout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.floatlayout.html?highlight=float) to put widgets on Image

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Image](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.image.html?highlight=image) to put image

```
<ProfileScreen>:
    name: 'profile'
    
    Image:
        source: '/home/furas/test/lenna.png'
        
    MDLabel:
        text: 'Welcome Nate'
        halign: 'center'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Back'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.2}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
```

Result:

[image]

---

Original image from Wikipedia: [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna)

---

**EDIT:**

Full code

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager


screen_helper = """
ScreenManager:
    MenuScreen:
    ProfileScreen:

<MenuScreen>:
    name: "menu"

    Image:
        source: '/home/furas/test/lenna.png'

    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Profile'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'profile'

<ProfileScreen>:
    name: 'profile'
    
    Image:
        source: '/home/furas/test/lenna.png'
        
    MDLabel:
        text: 'Welcome Nate'
        halign: 'center'
        color: (0, 0, 0)
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Back'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.2}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
"""


class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ProfileScreen(Screen):
    pass


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(ProfileScreen(name='profile'))


class DemoApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return screen


DemoApp().run()
```